# Hashing password at user signup on client side and database stores hash only. How to use the same salt again when logging in?

Tags: android, hash, cryptography, salt

So during user sign up the user enters (password + random salt) and sends that to the server.

During login the user enters (password + random salt?) and sends that to the server.

What do I have to do during the login part to make this work?

Comment: I mean to say, is the salt stored somewhere or what?

Comment: Yes, the salt is stored in the db along with the hashed password. [Googling this question](https://www.google.com.au/search?site=&source=hp&q=how+does+password+salt+work&oq=how+does+password+salt+work&gs_l=hp.3...733.9129.0.9402.58.26.1.0.0.2.1047.2704.3-2j2j7-1.5.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.hp..55.3.1540.0.dieL90iQgmY) returns a lot of results, did you check out any of those resources?

Comment: I believe you'd store the salt in the database with the rest of the user information. Not certain, though.

Comment: I checked the resources but I don't understand why the salt is stored in the db alongside the password. If the database is taken then can't the original password be retrieved easily from having the hashed password and the salt?

Answer (score 1):

The salt is generated by your server application, not by the user, and it will be stored together with your password in the database (it is not secret). A salt provided by the user would just be a second password.

The purpose of a salt is, that an attacker cannot build one single rainbow-table, to crack all passwords of your database at once. It does it even if it is known. Don't mix up salt and pepper, if you are interested in how to add a server-side secret, you can have a look at my tutorial about [secure password storing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: So is the password sent in plain text during first transmission? How does the client encrypt the password before its send to the server during login?

Comment: Nice guide BTW. It only covers server side though

Comment: @AlexMcG - Usually the password is sent plaintext over an encrypted SLL connection (HTTPS). For a website there are no other options, because whatever scripts you send to the client, a ManInTheMiddle will always be able to run the same scripts (or just strip them out). In case of an Android application, which will be installed by the user, you could use public-private-key encryption to protect the sent password.